# How should I write a serializer where a foreign key cold be set by SlugRelatedField OR by the foreign key serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a serializer as follow:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer for mymodel """

    version = VersionSerializer()
    device = DeviceSerializer()
    camera = CameraSerializer(many=True)
```

My code needs to be able to create instance of mymodel  knowing only one field on my camera foreign key.

I can create another serializer like this:

```
class MySerializerSlugRelated(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer for vision """

    version = VersionSerializer()
    device = DeviceSerializer()
    camera = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='my_slug_field', many=True, queryset=Camera.objects.all())
```

But it seems kind of dirty to recreate an other serializer just to be able to get one field in a different way, is there a clean way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can let the `MySerializerSlugRelated` inherit from `MySerializer`, and only redefine the `camera` field:

```
class MySerializerSlugRelated(MySerializer):
    camera = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='my_slug_field',
        many=True,
        queryset=Camera.objects.all()
    )
```